# Why adding delay when gcc -o2 optimization is used?

Tags: gcc, optimization, delay

I read an example code of STM32 with LCD and found below code, and its purpose is to write the LCD controller register index as output data of LCD controller.

```
void LCD_WR_REG(uint16_t regval)
{ 
    regval = regval;       // Necessary delay when using -o2 optimization
    LCD->LCD_REG = regval;
}
```

I searched for a while for -o2, but didn't get much useful info about the what the comment here means, or why a self assignment is necessary here.

Comment: With GCC, the `-O2` flags will clearly  optimize  the line `regval = regval;` to a no-op. The comment is just wrong. There will be no delay due to this line in `-O2`. I highly doubt they modified GCC so it behave differently in this case. It would be very surprising and a very bad idea. AFAIK, the standard GCC support the options/flags `-O2` and `-o` but not `-o2` so it might be a different option/flag.

Comment: Thanks, Richard. Yeah, I can't see any sense here neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment is simply wrong. This operation will be optimized out. I believe that this comment was written where the original author of the code is struggling to make it work and something else was in this line.

```
LCD_WR_REG:
        ldr     r3, .L3
        strh    r0, [r3]        @ movhi
        bx      lr
.L3:
        .word   1207993344
```

It could have some effect if `regval` was declared as `volatile`

```
void LCD_WR_REG1(volatile uint16_t regval)
{ 
    regval = regval;       // Necessary delay when using -o2 optimization
    LCD->LCD_REG = regval;
}
```

```
LCD_WR_REG1:
        sub     sp, sp, #8
        strh    r0, [sp, #6]    @ movhi
        ldrh    r3, [sp, #6]
        strh    r3, [sp, #6]    @ movhi
        ldr     r2, .L7
        ldrh    r3, [sp, #6]
        strh    r3, [r2]        @ movhi
        add     sp, sp, #8
        bx      lr
.L7:
        .word   1207993344
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Th7naabf7